# How to display child group values in the same row on Report Builder

Tags: reporting-services, grouping, reporting

I am creating a report using SSRS Report Builder to display the time a specific event happens.

My report has only two values (`hour` and `minutes`) and I have created a row group for the `hour` and a child row group for the `minute` values. The values are being aggregated correctly but the report is displaying each `minute` value in a separated row.

**Current display format** 
[image: Current display format]

**Expected display format** 
[image: Expected display format]

Comment: consider using column group in matrix.

Comment: Adding to Viking's comment, you'll also need to add a rank within each hour to the minutes so in hour 1, minute 0 will be ranked 1 and minute 23 would be rank 2 . In hour 2, minute 12 would be rank 1 and minute 15 rank 2. Then you would create a matrix with a column grouping based on the rank.

Comment: Hi @ViKiNG, Thank you very much for your answer. I created a matrix with a column group (Hour / Minute) and the displayed data is more or less in the format that I need. The only problem now is that the minute value is not displayed in the sencond cell of each line. Instead, now I have the cells 2,3, and 4 of the sencond row empty and the values related with the hour 2 is being displayed columns 5,6, and 7. I tried to use IFF to prevent the empty cells from being displayed but it did not work either.